# how to disable a cell based on p:selectOneMenu in cellEditing

Tags: jsf

I Want to get selectOneMenu value in bean but value is not getting correctly.SubstituteHoliday is a boolean variable.But,I getting false only for both yes and no selectItems.How could i get appropriate value for selectOneMenu.Based on that selectOneMenu value if yes means i want to diabled substitue date cell...

Thanks in advance...

```
       <p:dataTable id="manager" var="item" value="#{employeeWorkingHolidayBean.userListTwo}"
                    paginator="true" rows="10"
                    paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="2,5,10,15" 
                    editable="true" editMode="cell" style="width:600px;" styleClass="postformatte"
                    emptyMessage="No Employee Working Holiday Details found with given criteria" resizableColumns="true" > 

                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{employeeWorkingHolidayBean.onCellEdit}"
                    update=":form:growl"/>
                   <p:ajax event="colResize" update=":form:growl" listener="#{employeeWorkingHolidayBean.onResize}" />  


                <p:column headerText="Employee Id" width="90" >
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.employeeId}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Is Substitute Holiday">  
                <p:cellEditor>  
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.substituteHoliday}" /></f:facet>  
                <f:facet name="input">  
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{item.substituteHoliday}" style="width:100%">  
                        <f:selectItems value="#{employeeWorkingHolidayBean.subsholiday}"/>
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="subdate"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>  
                </f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor>  
                </p:column> 

                <p:column headerText="Substitute Date" >  
                <p:cellEditor>  
                <f:facet name="output"><p:calendar pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" yearRange="#{c-100}" navigator="true" showButtonPanel="true" value="#{item.substituteDate}"/></f:facet>  
                <f:facet name="input"><p:calendar id="subdate" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" yearRange="#{c-100}" navigator="true" showButtonPanel="true" value="#{item.substituteDate}" style="width:55px;" disabled="#{employeeWorkingHolidayBean.isdiableEffectdate}"/></f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor>  
                </p:column>

      </p:dataTable>
```

Bean:

```
      private Boolean isdiableEffectdate;
      public Boolean getIsdiableEffectdate() {
             return isdiableEffectdate;
         }

      public void setIsdiableEffectdate(Boolean isdiableEffectdate) {
        this.isdiableEffectdate = isdiableEffectdate;
        }

      public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event)
    {   

        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();  
        logger.info("Old value"+oldValue);
        logger.info("New value"+newValue);
        if(newValue.equals(true))
        {
            logger.info("enter if true");
            isdiableEffectdate=true;
        }
        else
        {
            logger.info("enter if false");
            isdiableEffectdate=false;
        }
        if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) 
        {  
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);  
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  

        }  

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a VCE (Value changeListener Event) for your select as,

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{item.substituteHoliday}"
    valueChangeListener="#{item.selectHolidayValueChangeListner}" 
    style="width:100%">
    <f:selectItems value="#{employeeWorkingHolidayBean.subsholiday}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" update="subdate"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And in your valueChangeListener method assign new value to global variable as,

```
public void selectHolidayValueChangeListner(ValueChangeEvent vce) {
    if (vce.getNewValue() != null) {
        substituteHoliday = vce.getNewValue().toString(); 
    }
}
```

Now, in your ajax method get the value of `substituteHoliday` and do whatever is required.